# Need to merge two Arrays like 1st value of first array followed by first value of second array and so on in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays
Say Example

```
A1 = [1,2,3]
A2 = [4,5,6]
```

The output I need is

```
A3 = [1,4,2,5,3,6]
```

i.e the output I need is first value of first array followed by first value of second array and so on

How can I achieve this in `PHP`

I tired some php array functions ,I didn't get the my required result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it (assuming that both arrays have the same size):

```
function merge($a1, $a2)
{
    $a3 = [];
    $len = count($a1);
    for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++)
    {
        $a3 []= $a1[$i];
        $a3 []= $a2[$i];
    }
    return $a3;
}

$a1 = [1, 2, 3];
$a2 = [4, 5, 6];
$a3 = merge($a1, $a2);
var_dump($a3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
$longer_arr = count($arr1) > count($arr2) ? $arr1 : $arr2;

$shorter_arr = count($arr1) > count($arr2) ? $arr2 : $arr1;

$combined_arr = [];
foreach($longer_arr as $key => $val){
    $combined_arr[] = $val;
    if(isset($shorter_arr[$key])){
        $combined_arr[] = $shorter_arr[$key];
    }
}
```

P.s I didn't tested it

Answer (score 0):

```php
function intersperse ($arr1, $arr2)
{
    $length = min (count($arr1), count($arr2));
    $result = [];
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        
        $result[] = $arr1[$i];
        $result[] = $arr2[$i];
    }
    
    return $result;
}

// --- Test

$array1 = [10,20,30,40];
$array2 = [1,2,3,4,5];
print_r (intersperse ($array1, $array2));

$array1 = [10,20,30];
$array2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
print_r (intersperse ($array1, $array2));

$array1 = [];
$array2 = [];
print_r (intersperse ($array1, $array2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr1 = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
$arr2 = [ 4, 5, 6 ];

$result =
  array_merge(
    ...array_map(
         fn($item1, $item2) => [ $item1, $item2 ],
         $arr1,
         $arr2
       )
  );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$output=[];
foreach($a1 as $i => $v){
    if(isset($a2[$i])){
        $output[] = $v;
        $output[] = $a2[$i];
    }
}
var_dump($output);
```